# What is the procedure for asking a question on PCG?

Tags: discussion

I posted a proposed puzzle in the Mark VIII sandbox regarding writing the most efficient algorithm to accomplish a specific task (identify Armstrong Numbers). It was a long question and I have no problem with the idea that it might not yet be ready for posting, but after a few early critical comments (which is fine) it has now languished for about three weeks.

From other meta comments it seems people want higher quality questions for PCG, which I *think* mine is. It is detailed and exercises actual useful skills (problem analysis and algorithm development) instead of the more typical "write the shortest program possible which means the winner will need to use a toy language to win" type questions.

I don't want to step on toes and post my question prematurely, yet I'm puzzled (HA!) by the lack of positive reaction to my post. There is nothing wrong with code golf, yet the "programming puzzles" part of "programming puzzles & code golf" seems to be actively ignored based on a comment to my proposed question (namely that it didn't fit the code golf format).

I guess my question is: Given how long it has been since my proposal has received feedback, do I just walk away from it, or should I be posting it assuming no further feedback is good news (no news being good news)? Or is there some other lesson I should take away from this?

Comment: We are now on Mark X.  I think it is probably ready to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been a big increase in use of the sandbox, which is good, but the downside is that new sandboxes have been created at a heavy rate and old ones have ceased to attract attention. I would suggest that as a general rule, if you think a question is ready but it seems to be ignored, edit it to say

> ---
>
> I will post this in 3 days unless there are further requests for clarification.

The action of editing will bump the sandbox.

Comment: Might it help to make the sandboxes specific to the question type? So one sandbox for codegolf, one for challenges, one for popularity contests, etc.?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, [previously discussed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/957/194)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Previously tried too.